# compiled program not executing, just has blinking cursor

Tags: c

trying to get this loop to run but it just has the cursor blinking. I am new to programing. Can you please help?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
       int i;
       i = 0

       while (i <= 5);
             {
              printf ( "i = %d" );
              i += 1;
        }
}
```

Comment: I would assume you at least know the language you're programming in?

Comment: Here, [let the compiler help](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/946719496cbe37bf). Each of those warning/error messages can be easily researched.

Comment: Remove the `;` in `while (i <= 5);`

Comment: Proper indentation of your code is ignored by the compiler but crucial for the human reader to spot simple bugs like this one.  Also consider learning how to use a debugger.  It would have told you quickly what was going o here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice how there was also a missing semicolon after `i = 0`, this will throw an error and prevent your program from continuing. Also, remove the semicolon after your while loop, it will not run the code inside with it present (And will just sit idle after skipping it). Your program should look like:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    i = 0;

    while (i <= 5)
    {
        printf ( "i = %d" );
        i += 1;
    } 
}
```

Comment: You need a semicolon after the `0`

Comment: `main` returns 0 implicitly.

Comment: @chris Thanks, I don't program in c.

Comment: also the output is coming out in a single row                                                i = 0i = 1i , but I wanted it in a colum reading i = 1, i = 2 etc.

Comment: I forgot a piece of that statement. In C, `main` returns 0 implicitly from C99 onward. Anyway, your `printf` is missing an argument.

Answer (score 0):

adding to the answer of Cyral, a semicolon indicates the end of a statement. if you have

```
   while (i <= 5);
         {
          printf ( "i = %d" );
          i += 1;
    }
```

the program will run statement by statement, so it will first run the while, doing nothing in every loop because it is a while with a blank instruction `;`. then it will run the next statement, that is everything inside the `{ }`.

the blinking cursor occurs because you increment `i` inside the statement that follows the while, so, the while, expecting an `i` thats grater than 5 to stop (an `i` that never increments inside the loop) enters in an infinite loop.